# position image combined with other graphics

Tags: graphics

Is there a way to directly transform an image?

This works but seems klunky :

```
Graphics[{Translate[ Raster@ImageData@image, {x,y}], .. other graphics objects .. }]
```

Just wondering if there is a better way..

Per JM.s comment, you can sort of do this with `ImageForwardTransformation`
I actually looked at those before asking the question and didn't think they would work, but now I went back and figured it out..

here is a simple translation:

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img]
ImageForwardTransformation[ img , (# + {x, y}) &, Background -> 1, 
        DataRange -> Full, PlotRange -> {{0, w + x}, {0, h + y}}]
```

This creates a new larger image, large enough to contain the transformed result but still anchored with a corner at {0,0}, so isn't really equivalent to simply translating the image.

Comment: Look up `ImageTransformation[]` and `ImageForwardTransformation[]`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, all you need is [Inset](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html).

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of Inset, useful indeed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a completely random illustration of how to use `Inset` to place an  image into a `Graphics`:

```
img = Image[
   Show[
    ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}],
    ImageSize -> 360, Background -> None],
   ImageResolution -> 144
   ];
ListAnimate@Table[
  Graphics[{
    Darker[Green],
    Disk[{.2, .4}, .6],
    Inset[Rotate[img, -t^2], {0, 1} + t {.9, -.8}]
    },
   Background -> Lighter[Gray],
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   ImageSize -> 360
   ],
  {t, 0, 1, .1}
  ]
```

[image: cow movie]

The image `img` has transparent background, and is superimposed on a green circle  in a `Graphics` object. When positioning the `Inset` inside `Graphics`, it is useful to always specify an explicit `PlotRange`, because it allows you to determine the position more accurately in the logical coordinate system of the other graphics objects. Here, I chose to make the left and bottom edges be at `0`, and the top and right correspond to `1`. In addition, I also included a `Rotate` command to show that you can add other transformations of the `img` inset.

Comment: Thanks for this illustration of "the cow jumped over the (green) moon".